Unable to validate access token of Nodejs Api on APIM
I have a B2C tenant configured with a sign-in flow. I'm attempting to validate an access token received from msal-angular within Azure API Management (APIM) in order to call a Node.js API. However, when making requests to the endpoint, I encounter a 401 Unauthorized error. I suspect this issue may be related to scopes, but I'm uncertain. Despite setting up an exposed API and defining a scope, I'm still unable to access the API endpoints with a valid token.
Below is the code of angular app.
let request = {
  scopes: ['<tenantname>.onmicrosoft.com/<clientId>/access_as_user']
};
this.msalService.loginPopup(request).subscribe((response: AuthenticationResult) => {
    this.msalService.instance.setActiveAccount(response.account);
    // callNodeJsAPi with response.accessToken, here it gives 401
})

Below is the code of APIM.
<when condition="@( !(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>(" isPublicEndpoint")) )">
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401"
        failed-validation-error-message="Invalid credentials" require-scheme="Bearer" output-token-variable-name="jwt">
        <openid-config
            url="https:///<tenantname>.b2clogin.com/<tenantname>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_sign_in" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>
                <clientId>
            </audience>
        </audiences>
    </validate-jwt>
    <set-header name="userid" exists-action="override">
        <value>@{
            return ((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt"])?.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("name", "");
            }</value>
    </set-header>
</when>

I checked this SO Answer as well, and was confused because the scope mentioned in this article starts with api:// but for me its tenant-name/clientid/scopename

I enabled logs for APIM and checked APP Insights was getting TokenInvalidIssuer: at validate-jwt adding issuer in openid-config solved my issue. After resolving APIM Policy should look like this:
<when condition="@( !(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<bool>(" isPublicEndpoint")) )">
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401"
        failed-validation-error-message="Invalid credentials" require-scheme="Bearer" output-token-variable-name="jwt">
        <openid-config
            url="https:///<tenantname>.b2clogin.com/<tenantname>.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p=B2C_1_sign_in" />
        <openid-config url="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
        <audiences>
            <audience>
                <clientId>
            </audience>
        </audiences>
    </validate-jwt>
    <set-header name="userid" exists-action="override">
        <value>@{
            return ((Jwt)context.Variables["jwt"])?.Claims.GetValueOrDefault("name", "");
            }</value>
    </set-header>
</when>

